# Most appropriate AI for parameter weighting?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have data of this form:

```
[(v1, A1, B1), (v2, A2, B2), (v3, A3, B3), ...]
```

The `v`s correspond to the data elements and the `A`s and `B`s to numerical values characterizing the `v`s.

A human looking at this data can look at it and see which tuple seems the best "match" according to the `A` and `B` values. I want a form of AI that I could train by picking one of these tuples as the best, and that would adjust the weights given to `A` and `B`.

Basically, each tuple represents an approximation to a value. `A` represents an error and `B` represents the complexity of each approximation. I want some compromise between error and complexity by assigning them different weightings. I want to run several trials with approximations to different values, and choose the one I think looks the best, and have the AI adjust the weightings correspondingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described is also known as a [model selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_selection) problem, something often encountered in machine learning and statistics. You basically have some models that fit your data by some measure of goodness (typically measured as error or log likelihood) and those models have some complexity measure (typically the number of parameters in the model). You want to pick the best fitting model and penalize its complexity because that can be a sign of [overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Typically, the degree to which overfitting can affect you is driven by the size of your data. But there are some measures that explicitly allow you to trade off model fitness and complexity:

- [Akaike information criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion)
- [Bayesian information criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion)
- [Regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29)

Choose a model based on your data as above can bias the model choice toward the data. Thus, this is done typically using a [validation set and then evaluated on a test set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_set).

I don't know if your approach in having an algorithm solve this problem is a good one. Typically it is dependent on your data and some degree of intuition. The meta-machine-learning technique you described probably won't be too reliable, in my opinion. Better to start with some more principled and simpler ideas first.